# NAs introduced by coercion - mixed vector

Tags: r

NAs introduced by coercion. How to get around this? Thank you for your help.

```
water <- 785.5
volume_water <- as.numeric(as.character(c("water", water)))
volume_water
[1]    NA 785.5
```

This is dataframe called data

```
  Substance     v1
1       abc   12.5
2      defg  100.0
3      hijk  100.0
4      abfg    2.0
```

I want to achieve:

```
rbind(data, volume_water)
  Substance     v1
1       abc   12.5
2      defg  100.0
3      hijk  100.0
4      abfg    2.0
5     water  785.5
```

Comment: Are you planning on making multiple vectors like `volume_water`?  If so, you may want to use a `data.frame`, which can support a different data type for each column.  If not, I'd suggest a `list`.  Vectors (and their 2D analogs, matrices) are typically used for single data types.  Let me know your intended use and I'll create a real answer

Comment: See updated question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I would create the object as a data frame, i.e.:

`volume_water = data.frame(Substance="water", v1=785.5)`

Then you can `rbind` it with `data`.